# How to get get unique and total count from Mongodb sub-documents for each main doc

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Mongodb

I want to count the number of times main message is displayed on a web page and unique IP addresses for that message. I have main doc with content and multiple aux docs with client's IP address. The main and aux are liked with uniqueId as below:

```
Main_Collection
{
    "uniqueId" : "25d422a0-b916-11ea-b343-5bc178e798e9",
    “Message” : “Some random message displayed on a web page”,
},
{
    "uniqueId" : "25d422a0-b916-11ea-b343-5bcaaaeeee”,
    “Message” : “Another random message displayed on a web page”,
}
```

```
Aux_Collection
{
    "uniqueId" : "25d422a0-b916-11ea-b343-5bc178e798e9",
    “IPAddr” : “192.168.10.12”
},
{
    "uniqueId" : "25d422a0-b916-11ea-b343-5bc178e798e9",
    “IPAddr” : “192.168.10.44”
},
{
    "uniqueId" : "25d422a0-b916-11ea-b343-5bc178e798e9",
    “IPAddr” : “192.168.10.12”
},
{
    "uniqueId" : "25d422a0-b916-11ea-b343-5bc178e798e9",
    “IPAddr” : “192.168.10.56”
},
{
    "uniqueId" : "25d422a0-b916-11ea-b343-5bc178e798e9",
    “IPAddr” : “192.168.10.12”
},
{
    "uniqueId" : "25d422a0-b916-11ea-b343-5bcaaaeeee",
    “IPAddr” : “192.168.10.46”
},
{
    "uniqueId" : "25d422a0-b916-11ea-b343-5bcaaaeeee",
    “IPAddr” : “192.168.10.46”
},
{
    "uniqueId" : "25d422a0-b916-11ea-b343-5bcaaaeeee",
    “IPAddr” : “192.168.10.33”
}
```

Here’s what I would like to get back.

```
{
    "uniqueId" : "25d422a0-b916-11ea-b343-5bc178e798e9",
    “Message” : “Some random message displayed on a web page”,
    “UniqueIPs”: 3,   // Number of unique IPs
    “TotalIPs” : 5 // Total records in the aux collection
},
{
    "uniqueId" : "25d422a0-b916-11ea-b343-5bcaaaeeee",
    “Message” : “Another random message displayed on a web page”,
    “UniqueIPs”: 2,   // Number of unique IPs
    “TotalIPs” : 3 // Total records in the aux collection
}
```

I have been able to run an aggregation to get totals but the unique IP count within each group has been challenging. Other examples I looked at assume known unique names but in this case the IP address is not previously known and can be random.

Comment: I would try $group with $push and $addToSet then another stage with $size for each of the sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `$lookup` stage in combination with `$group` with `$addToSet` and `$sum` to get the required result.

```
db.Main_Collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "Aux_Collection",
            "let": {"sourceUID": "$uniqueId"},
            "pipeline": [
                {
                    "$match": {
                        "$expr": {
                            "$eq": ["$uniqueId", "$$sourceUID"]
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "$group": {
                        "_id": null,
                        "UniqueIPs": {
                            "$addToSet": "$IPAddr"
                        },
                        "TotalIPs": {"$sum": 1}
                    }
                },
            ],
            "as": "ipAddresses"
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "uniqueId": 1,
            "Message": 1,
            "UniqueIPs": {"$size": {"$arrayElemAt": ["$ipAddresses.UniqueIPs", 0]}},
            "TotalIPs": {"$arrayElemAt": ["$ipAddresses.TotalIPs", 0]},
        }
    }
])
```